# Can a team Work in Unreal engine 4 with source control using different versions of UE4

Tags: git, unreal-engine4

I am using Gitas source control with UE4 and my teammates are using different versions of Unreal. Will it cause problems for them? I know that Unreal will ask to open a copy of the project if it is from earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with source control : using an older version of UE4, you will not be able to open any asset saved with a newer version !

Comment: So team members must use the same Unreal Version ?

Comment: @AchrafGarai yes, they must use the same version